# Morphism of algebraic function fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Let $k$ be a field and $T$ be an indeterminate. Consider $y\in\overline{k(T)}$. So, $y$ is a root of an irreducible polynomial $P(X)\in k(T)[X]$: $P(X)=\sum_{i=0}^na_i(T)X^i$ where the $a_i$'s are in $k(T)$. Each element $z\in k(t)(y)$ can be uniquely written as:
$z=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\gamma_i(T)y^i$ with the $\gamma_i$'s are in $k(T)$. Denote by $\beta$ a root (in $\overline{k(T)}$) of the polynomial $Q(X)=\sum_{i=0}^na_i(h(T))X^i$, where $h(T)\in k(T)$. Define the application $\sigma:k(T)(y)\to k(T)(\beta)$ by $\sigma(z)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\gamma_i(h(T))\beta^i$. I want to prove that $\sigma$ is a $k$-morphism of fields.

Any clue to prove that would be welcome.

Comment: Please don't mix $t$ and $T$. And $Q$ doesn't have to be irreducible, try with $h(T)\in k$ or $P(X)= X^2-T, Q(X)= X^2-T^2$.

Comment: Sorry. I changed the post. I forgot to remove the no longer true assertions.

Answer (score 0):

Let $h(T)\in k(T),\not \in k$ and the field isomorphism $$\sigma : F=k(T)\to \sigma(F)=k(h(T)),\qquad T\to h(T)$$

Then it is completely obvious that $$F[X]/(\sum_{j=0}^n a_j X^j) \to \sigma(F)[X]/(\sum_{j=0}^n \sigma(a_j) X^j), \qquad \sum_{m=0}^{n-1} f_m X^m \to \sum_{m=0}^{n-1} \sigma(f_m) X^m$$
is a ring isomorphism.

No need that $\sum_{j=0}^n a_j X^j$ is irreducible in $F[X]$.